# loop that breaks when program closes

Tags: server

How would I check with this command `ps aux | grep java` to make a while loop that would end if this process is off?

The idea is so if the server, in my case a minecraft server, crashes or closes then the backup stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while pidof java &> /dev/null; do
      sleep 1;
done
```